# Multiple answers saying the same thing

Tags: discussion

Often, I see people posting duplicate answers to the same question. [Example scenario](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791589/download-and-using-ubuntu-16-04-2016-6-daily-build/791593). Is this a problem? Should I flag them?

Comment: What are you going to flag them as?

Comment: If the answers were both posted at almost exactly the same time, I usually leave them be. If an answer comes in later than another with pretty much the same message, leave it if it contains more detail (adds to the other answer). If it contains less, like the example you linked, I would leave a comment asking what it adds to the already existing answer.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Thanks for that.

Comment: @edwinksl Moderator attention - does not add to current answer.

Comment: @CollDue96 Why not just downvote the answer for not being useful? It would also be nice to leave a comment to show how the answerer can improve his/her answer. And also remember to retract your downvote if the answer has indeed improved.

Comment: @edwinksl that is a good idea. You've been around so long I can imagine you have dealt with these sort of scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks fine, both are different enough, one person probably thought they could elaborate a bit more, and given the times he may have been forming the answer before or near the time the other one was posted -

[Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

I wouldn't flag them unless it is directly word for word the same.  We should be able to encourage a later answer if it is more detailed, has screens, is better, or better worded, or even stated more simply.

So a simple vote up/down should do the trick on if you think the answer is useful or not.

Comment: Ok, sure, but the later answer is the least elaborated.